# sending struct to form field in golang

Tags: go

I have a struct which I have to send to an api and it's a post request. But the input are form field. And the fields contains strings, integer, float and image. 
I tried to use WriteField function but since this function only takes strings as parameters, I can't process integer and float. How do I do that. Here is my struct and the code snippet.

```
c := finalObject{
    name: Name,
    ProfilePic:"/img/unknown.jpg",
    owner:"Mr Hall",
    latitude:26.5473828,
    longitude:88.4249179,
    opendays:"Monday-Friday",
    openhours:"10am to 5pm",
    catId:82,
    address:address,
    phone_number:2312312,
    mobile_number:312312,
    email:"dsdas@a.com",
  }

  url := "https://abcd.com/a"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)
    b, err := json.Marshal(c)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
    var jsonStr = []byte(b)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "AUTH_TOKEN")
    req.Header.Set("enctype", "multipart/form-data")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
    fmt.Printf("%#v", c);
  }
```

Comment: What format does the server expect (application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data)?

Comment: Turning ints and floats into strings is as simple as fmt.Sprintf("%d", i) and fmt.Sprintf("%f", f) so this cannot be the problem, or?

Comment: server expect multipart/form-data @CeriseLimón

Comment: Create multipart form body and WriteField(name, fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)) for each field.

Answer (score 1):

The Form values in HTTP form are sent as string values only.

If you have the liberty of deciding the form keys as well then you can add the whole structure as a json-encoded string against a generic "data" field and send the request. Else, you'd have to convert the structure values to string representation to send them in request.

Comment: But how do I convert a struct into String

Comment: b, err := json.Marshal(c)
b which is a byte array can be typecast in a string variable and then again typecast and unmarshalled at server end